# Does anyone know what type of chilli plant this is?

Tags: identification, chili

I posted photos here last year but the plant was too young to produce fruit. Here are new photos of the same plant with chilli's growing on it. What type of chilli plant is this? My uncle was told the seeds were a Thai fire chilli, but there are so many varieties of them. Is this an ornamental plant?

[image]

Comment: Plants can be both ornamental and useful. To me, it's merely ornamental, but that's due to how I feel about eating peppers of any sort. If you like hot peppers, give one of the ripe ones a try... it's either one you like, or not.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know what type of Chili it is? I am not sure as there are a lot of different types of Thai fire chilies

Comment: There are many sorts with such habits (maybe not so much, that starts with white peppers). Colour of flowers helps also on identify. But I saw so many cultivars that I gave up to remember names and habits. In would also recommend to try it (to check how hot they are).

Answer (score 4):

The shape of the fruit, combined with them growing upwards, will narrow it down, but not much.  For example [tabasco](https://www.southdevonchillifarm.co.uk/online-shop/chilli-seeds/tabasco-chilli-seeds/) grows like this (and also shows ripe and unripe fruit together with that range of colours).  The shape of the bush depends so much on how it's treated, light levels, fertiliser, etc. that I wouldn't read too much into that.

I can't find *Thai fire* online, but [hot Thai](https://www.marshalls-seeds.co.uk/chilli-pepper-hot-thai-plants-x3-pid11208.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsrPS4Nq22QIVCLnACh2Pig1dEAQYASABEgLt4_D_BwE) aka [Thai hot](https://www.southdevonchillifarm.co.uk/online-shop/chilli-seeds/thai-hot-chilli-seeds/) seems to pass through a dark green, almost brown, before ripening, instead of the yellow/orange in your picture.  It does however have the up-growing fruit (unlike, say, habanero or jalapeño).

I doubt you'll be able to track it down definitively.

Comment: I immediately thought tabasco.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris H says, I'm afraid it's quite impossible to identify a species from a picture. Many chili varieties have fruits that grow upright. Thai fire seems to be a good possibility.

https://www.peperzaden.be/catalogsearch/result/?q=thai+fire&x=0&y=0

Note however, that all chillies are edible, also the ornamental ones. The difference only lies in the form of the plant, and the taste of the fruit.
Yours however doesn't seem to be ornamental.

Comment: I see you don't get "Thai fire" either, but several hits that match one of the two words.

Comment: Ok thanks Chris. I tried an orange one yesterday and I deseeded it. It still had some heat.

Answer (score 0):

It is "Prik Ki Nu" Chilli.
The main character of this type of chilli is shot stem but very spicy